# How to make a normal user input of time and date to get it added in mysql as timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

In the user interface, i have a text field to enter date in dd/mm/yyyy format and there is another textbox for time in hh:mm format and another dropdown box to specify am or pm. All these three fields will let the user to enter the date,time and am/pm manually. I prefered to use this primitive method as per the requirement of the project.

Now i want all these values to be added in mysql in timestamp format to make it easier to fetch and manipulate. Please suggest me how can i achieve this.

```
<?
$date = '21'.'/'.'11'.'/'.'2011';
$time = '12'.':'.'00';
$ampm = "am";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y h:i a',
 sprintf('%s %s %s', $date, $time, $ampm),
   new DateTimeZone('Country/Region'));



$mysqlDateString = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mktime](http://php.net/mktime) in conjunction with the correct format to [date](http://php.net/date) by sending your user input to [explode](http://php.net/explode), like so:

```
$date = '22/11/2011'; $date_pieces = explode( '/', $date);
$time = '08:35'; $time_pieces = explode( ':', $time);
$am_pm = 'PM';

$mysql_timestamp = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime( 
    $time_pieces[0] + ( $am_pm == 'AM' ? -12 : 12), // Hour - Convert AM/PM to 24-hr format
    $time_pieces[1], // Minute
    0, // Second
    $date_pieces[1], // Month
    $date_pieces[0], // Day
    $date_pieces[2])); // year
```

Now `$mysql_timestamp` is a valid entry for a datetime column.

If you need a UNIX timestamp, just remove the call to `date`, like so:

```
$unix_timestamp = mktime( 
    $time_pieces[0] + ( $am_pm == 'AM' ? -12 : 12), // Hour - Convert AM/PM to 24-hr format
    $time_pieces[1], // Minute
    0, // Second
    $date_pieces[1], // Month
    $date_pieces[0], // Day
    $date_pieces[2]);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jiQdTh)

**Edit:** As per Phil's comments below, be sure to set a correct timezone with [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Should probably set a timezone using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference on my tests - Can you post an example where the output is different when different timezones are inputted?

Comment: The unix timestamp will be different for different timezones. For example, using your date and `Australia/Melbourne`, I get `1321954500`. For `Australia/Perth` I get `1321965300`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Assuming the form fields have been POSTed, roughly validated and collected into variables...

```
// assume $date, $time, $ampm

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y h:i a',
    sprintf('%s %s %s', $date, $time, $ampm),
    new DateTimeZone('Country/Region'));

$unixTimestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();

$mysqlDateString = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If you're storing the date/time as a MySQL date/time string, you should probably store the timezone as well or else it will be impossible to retrieve accurate data.

Comment: @nickb PHP 5.3.0 released on Jun 30, 2009. I'd say it's been long enough to stop using that disclaimer

Comment: @Phil that is to return unixTimestamp. But i would like to add it as normal mysql timestamp. Is it posible using objects as u did above ? nickb's solution worked..!

Comment: @Bala.C I've added a MySQL date string version to the answer

Comment: @Phil You'd think, but then again we still have people using XP / IE6 :)

Comment: I tried your solution phil..but it throws an error..posibly, i got it wrong..! I have posted the code above.

Comment: @Bala.C - You need to pass a [correct timezone](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) to `DateTimeZone`.

Comment: @Bala.C You need to use a [proper timezone string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), not literally `Country/Region`

Answer (score 1):

There is loads of information over at [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) about time conversions. In your case I think [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) would work.